# Reading from a Zip Archive

Tags: c, file, zip, zlib

While using **zlib 1.2.7** and **minizip** to read zip archives, I found that its only possible for me to read into a byte buffer. I'm passing this data over to another library for processing, but this library requires that the data be in the form of a `FILE*`.

Is it possible for me to create a `FILE*` using a byte buffer in memory?

Comment: zlib is for reading/writing compressed files, not zip archives. For that see e.g. [ziplib](http://nih.at/libzip/).

Comment: He is using minizip which also works with zip archives.  Both minizip and ziplib use zlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this question using a C++ tag? C's  isn't extensible with respect to its sources and destinations. Thus, you'd need to rely on platform specific extensions. In C++ you can create a suitable stream buffer to plug things into IOStreams. However, a .zip archive is an archive not a flat file, i.e., you'd need to think about how to specific the objects you actually want to extract. This is still doable, though.

Comment: I'm only going to be reading from an archive that I /know/ has a specific number of files and all those files have specific names. Is that what you meant in that statement before your last one?

Comment: Yes, roughly. I wouldn't implement a stream buffer to extract any specific file or set of files but do it in a way to specify the .zip file and the the contained file. The API I used for decompressing, zlib, doesn't provide an interface to access components of an archive. It seems there is an add-on, though: http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that add-on. Mostly because I'm already using it ;o (Sorry I forgot to mention that earlier).